# Change content of popup.html from script.js?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension, I am sending an ajax request to some URL which returns JSON data and it works perfectly, but I want to display that data on the extension.

Script.js

```
var link = location.href;

$(document).ready(function() {
   url(link);
})

function url(link) {
 // use "link" variable to get the link here

var data = {js_link: link}
$.ajax({
   console.log("2"); // THIS IS PRINTING ON THE CONSOLE
   url: 'some url',
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   type: 'POST',
   success: function (response) {
     console.log(response.score); //This works
     document.getElementById('score').innerHTML=response.score;
   },
   error: function (error) {
       console.log("ERROR");
       console.log(error);
   },
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
});

}
console.log("1");
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body style="width:450px; height:420px;margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-offset-2">
        <h3>Moderator</h3>
      </div>
    </div><hr/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-offset-2">
        <h6>Polarising index is <div id="score">8</div></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Hello Extensions",
"description" : "Base Level Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*"],
  "js": [ "jquery.js","script.js"]
  }
],
"permissions": [
  "tabs","http://*/*"
],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
"commands": {
  "_execute_browser_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Shift+F",
      "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+F"
    },
    "description": "Opens hello.html"
  }
}
}
```

Also, console.log(response.score) appears a little late after the page is refreshed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How is popup.html included in your document? Is it a separate file?Are you referencing your js in html with <script> tag?

Comment: Yes, it's a separate file. `popup.html` is the first file that open when the extension is loaded. All files are in the same directory.

Comment: I am referencing my js in HTML by mentioning it in manifest.js. Is it not enough?

Comment: it could be that html is not yet ready at that point so your getElementById is firing too early.

Comment: I have updated the script.js in the question. It was already in the function. And even if html is not ready, then what's the solution?

Comment: Alternatively do window.onload = function() {//all your code here}

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Extensions</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="width:450px; height:420px;margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-offset-2">
        <h3>Moderator</h3>
      </div>
    </div><hr/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-offset-2">
        <h6>Polarising index is <div id="score">8</div></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

script.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log("DOMContentLoaded");
    Load();
}, false);

var link = location.href;

function Load() {
    url(link);
}

function url(link) {
    console.log("AJAX Start");
    var data = {js_link: link}
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some url',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("AJAX Success. SCORE =>");
            console.log(response.score); //This works
            document.getElementById('score').innerHTML=response.score;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("AJAX Error. Error =>");
            console.log(error);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    });

}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said, now the function url(link) is not even calling as I console logged inside it.

Comment: I think its because chrome does not allow inline javascript to be run.

Comment: Chrome does allow inline JavaScript. I use it daily on all my applications.

If the console.log is not executing within the Load function, this means your document ready is not firing.

You will need to provide more information on your structure for us to help you more.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution

Comment: Completely correct. I missed the part that this is for an extension. The answer has been updated.

Comment: It still doesn't work this way. However, please check the edits I made to the question. I have given all the information(HTML completely updated, script.js updated) and with `$(document).ready` `url(link)` is being called. Do I have to reference script.js in HTML also, as it is already being referenced by manifest.json?

Comment: I will have a look and update my question with a comment if I have a solution.

Comment: Have you tried the latest example with document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'...? You can check my answer.

Comment: Yes did that. Console.log(2) was not printing

Comment: $.ajax({
   console.log("2"); //

This will not work. Your console.log(2); is incorrect in syntax as it is breaking your JavaScript Object.

Rather do this:

var data = {js_link: link}
console.log("2"); // THIS IS PRINTING ON THE CONSOLE
$.ajax({
   url: 'some url',

Comment: I don't understand man, nothing is now printing on the console. Not even `Document ready and l`

Comment: Try the the latest answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your script

```
var link = location.href;

$(document).ready(function() {
  url(link);
});

function url(link) {
    var data = {js_link: link}
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some url',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.score); //This works
            document.getElementById('score').innerHTML=response.score;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("ERROR");
            console.log(error);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    });

}
```

Comment: The `url(link)` function is being called as console outputs `2`. But still the same error. Do I need to reference script.js in HTML?
Please check my updated question. It has all the information now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have misunderstood the structure of a browser extension. You're declaring `script.js` in your manifest as a *content script*. This means that it's going to be injected into every single page the user goes to - probably not what you want. (You might want to have something to get the URL of any given page, but see the last paragraph for that. You probably *don't* want to be triggering a web request every time the user visits any page, which is what your current setup does.)

Also, as others have pointed out, you have a syntax error in your `script.js` at `console.log("2")`. Please update your question with the real code you're having trouble with, as the code you have currently wouldn't even run.

Also, you won't be able to load JQuery or `popper.js` from an external URL in your popup, because of [extension content security policies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). If you want to use them, the easiest way is to just download local copies to the same folder as your project and reference them from your `popup.html` (it looks like you already have a copy of `jquery.js` locally, since you're referencing that in your manifest).

Finally, what is the functionality you're looking for here? If you want to show something in the popup based on the current tab url, then you don't need a content script just to get a `location.href`. When your popup gets opened, you can have it [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging) to your background page, which can use Chrome's [tab API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) to get the URL of the current tab and return it to the popup.